# Swift: how to call the function which calls a random function?

Tags: swift, function, random

I have four functions which I want to activate randomly. This is the code I have so far, which I get no errors from. However, I get an error "Expression Resolves to an unused function" when I try to call the createSquare() function.

```
func createSquare () -> () -> () {
    let squares = [self.squareOne, self.squareTwo, self.squareThree, self.squareFour]

    let randomSquare = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(squares.count)))

    return squares[randomSquare]

}
if gameIsOn == true {
    createSquare()
}
```

How can I successfully call the function createSquare()?

```
func squareOne() {
    square1.isHidden = false
}
```

And squareTwo, squareThree, squareFour are all similar with different numbers.

Comment: show the code for `squareOne`

Comment: createSquare()()

Comment: How about `squareTwo`, `squareThree` and `squareFour`? You add them into the question by clicking on the edit button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `createSquare()` returns a closure that you never invoke (that's the "unused function" mentioned in the warning message).

You need to call the function, for example, like this:

```
let randomFunction = createSquare()
randomFunction()
```

You can also call it right away with a somewhat less readable syntax:

```
createSquare()()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func createSquare() {
    
    let randomNumber = Int.random(in: 0...3)
    
    if randomNumber == 0 {
        squareOne()
    } else if randomNumber == 1 {
        squareTwo()
    } else if randomNumber == 2 {
        squareThree()
    } else if randomNumber == 3 {
        squareFour()
    }
}
```